# Why is this MySQL SELECT performing so slowly despite indexing?

Tags: mysql, select, configuration

I have a large MyISAM table A (500m entries) that connects two other tables B,C with a n:m relation.

So my table A looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id_b` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_c` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Uniqueness` (`id_c`,`id_b`),
  KEY `id_b` (`id_b`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every entity in B is related to 1-12 entities in C with an average of 8 and a mode of 10.

Every entitiy in C is related to 100-500 entities in B (but this is linearly growing over time).

Now for a specific entitiy c I want a list of all other entities in C that it is connected to through B and how many entities in B they are connect through.
Or more directly: I have a specific c, that is connected 100-500 b's which are each connected to a handful of other entities in C. I want to know which C's the b's are connect with, and how often.

My simplified query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(OtherA.id_b), OtherA.id_c FROM A
INNER JOIN A OtherA
ON OtherA.id_b = A.id_b
WHERE A.id_c=[MY_SPECIFIC_C_ID]
GROUP BY OtherA.id_c
```

And takes over a second to execute. As described above, the inner join yields at max a few thousand results and the group reduces it to a few hundred. As far as I can tell I indexed correctly, so I am confused why this query is taking so long.

EXPLAIN yields the following result:

```
row1
id--------------1
select_type-----SIMPLE
table-----------A
type------------ref
possible_keys---Uniqueness,id_b
key-------------Uniqueness
key_len---------5
ref-------------const
rows------------462
Extra-----------Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
row2
id--------------1
select_type-----SIMPLE
table-----------OtherA
type------------ref
possible_keys---id_b
key-------------id_b
key_len---------5
ref-------------THISDB.A.id_b
rows------------8
Extra-----------Using where
```

As suggested I have tried manually extracting the list of id_b's:

```
[concated_list] = select group_concat(distinct id_b) as id_list from A where id_c = ...;
```

And then running

```
SELECT count(id_b), id_c FROM A WHERE id_b IN([concated_list]) GROUP BY id_c
```

The first query is instant, the second query takes almost as long as the original query, so it was suggested that I need to fine-tune my MySQL Vars. Where do I start?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(id_b), id_c FROM A WHERE id_b IN([concated_list]) GROUP BY id_c

results in:

id--------------1
select_type-----SIMPLE
table-----------A
type------------range
possible_keys---id_b
key-------------id_b
key_len---------5
ref-------------NULL
rows------------802
Extra-----------Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

MySQL version is `5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`.

Comment: Alright, I tried count(OtherA.id_b) and unfortunately it did not speed up the query. Table B is indexed by id_b and Table C is indexed by id_c, but that shouldn't matter since they are not in the query.
I'd be fine with the query taking 100-200ms, but I can't afford 1s+, since I am expecting it to increase linearly over time.

Comment: what's the results of running the `EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN to the main question

Comment: Could you (for testing purpose) try extracting the id_b list manually and giving it to the query? `select group_concat(distinct id_b) as id_list from A where id_c = ...;` and stuffing that list into the outer query?

Comment: Alright, the extracting of the id_b list takes less than a millisecond. The outer query takes the same time as before (I ran `SELECT count(id_b), id_c FROM A WHERE id_b IN([concated_list]) GROUP BY id_c`).

Comment: OK, then the problem is at least isolated - finding the id_b entries in A. At least you proved that the index is correctly used, that the list is not long, and that everything works fine - just too slow. This sounds like moving into dba.stackexchange, where they have the harder drugs, like checking if Index Buffer is big enough (count local hit/miss before and after), or you check if you can identify big blocks of id_b (independent of id_c) or if you can work out id_c which is rarely used (old) and split them off. 500m is quite a lot, in the end.

Comment: You state you are using indexing but haven't shown your index definitions here?

Comment: They are at the very top in the table create. The query inner joins A with A, so these are the only indexes that should matter.

Comment: My bad, misread the technology. Can you add an explain for the last query please? ("And then running"). I suspect the index may be being skipped for this as too much of the index is required.

Comment: I added the `EXPLAIN` to the question

Comment: There you go. The index is being skipped as the optimiser has decided a table scan is more efficient than reading a large portion of the index and then going to table. I believe that's the case, hopefully someone with more MySQL specific knowledge will chime in with a more codified/concise answer.

Comment: I would try adding an index on `(id_b, id_c)` as well - and removing the `(id_b)`.

Comment: Please also add the version of MySQL you are using. And why are you still working with MyISAM?

Comment: I tried your proposed (id_b,id_c) index on a new table with only 10k entries and the EXPLAIN showed that it was using the index properly. Thus I am now adding the Index to the main table and will update in a few hours if it worked.

MySQL version is `5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`.

The reason I am using MyISAM is that I am a total MySQL noob and with the default settings my routine took 10 times longer in InnoDB, so I just went with the lazy solution.
However I am doing about 5k INSERTS/UPDATES per second and very, very few SELECTS, and as far as I can tell that's the case MyISAM is good for?

Comment: You can try find out how long your query takes for a single id_b, with "=" instead of "where in". You should look if your keys fit into key buffer, estimate by file sizes of .idx files, compared to key_buffer_size. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size . `Key_read_requests` have to be around 100x as many as `Key_reads` `(show variables like 'key%')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `EXPLAIN SELECT count(id_b), id_c FROM A WHERE id_b IN([concated_list]) GROUP BY id_c` shows, the reason for the slow `SELECT` is that the `id_b INDEX` is not being used. Replacing the `id_b INDEX` with a `(id_b,id_c) INDEX` solved the problem and reduced the query time by 99% from 1-2s to 10-20ms depending on the specific `c_id`.

Thank you so much @ everyone for solving the problem, there is no way I would have been able to resolve this myself.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since the first try with a subselect lead into doom, it might be necessary to split the table into a hot range and a "cold" range. That solution only could help if you have some criteria for id_c and id_b, which shows if this id_c will be read often or rarely, for example the age of this. But even deleting from such a big table is not so easy, it would need an optimize which takes ages. It would need some clever ideas to get as little as possible reads which "overlap" between both tables, but since you want to read all rows with id_b from different id_c, there will be cases where you need two queries and adding afterwards.

As already stated in the comments, look into key_reads and key_reads_request with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'KEY%';`. Check if key_buffer_size is big enough (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-key-cache.html). You could arrange two different key buffers, one only for that specific table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-key-caches.html), one for the rest.

The suggestion with an index id_b, id_c should help a lot, since your query can then be processed completely in index, not from the (not bigger) "real table".

Try doing an `analyze table A` in low-traffic-times.

It really would help to split the table into many sections, especially for `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and `ANALYZE TABLE`, but your kind of query makes that really hard.

Doomed original solution:
I think you create many N x N - block of rows, where N is the number of rows in tableA with identical `id_b` values, since the join has to combine the `id_b` - blocks. So when you have many rows for some id_b, time squares up with that number.

It might help to use subselect in that case.

EDIT: EDIT undone.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), OtherA.id_c 
FROM A OtherA where OtherA.id_b in (
    select DISTINCT id_b from A where A.id_c = [MY_SPECIFIC_C_ID]
)
GROUP BY OtherA.id_c
```

So the id_b can be selected in one scan and then can be sent through the index to find the right rows.

EDIT: 
The Explain inserted by the Questioner shows that this subselect is a very bad idea in that case, no wonder it takes forever:

EXPLAIN on the suggested query looks like this:

```
row1
id--------------1
select_type-----PRIMARY
table-----------OtherA
type------------index
possible_keys---NULL
key-------------Uniqueness
key_len---------10
ref-------------NULL
rows------------496167246
Extra-----------Using where; Using index
row2
id--------------2
select_type-----DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
table-----------A
type------------reg
possible_keys---Uniqueness, id_b
key-------------Uniqueness
key_len---------10
ref-------------const,func
rows------------1
Extra-----------Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation. The query you suggested however is not the solution - it's still executing after several minutes.

Looking at the query I don't really understand why it's taking so long. Is IN() not using indexes?

Comment: Could you please interrupt that and give an `EXPLAIN`? Sounds strange. Also your Explain (8 x 462) should take very short time. Try looking for big blocks, like `select id_b, count(*) as cnt from A group by id_b oder by cnt desc limit 50;` and if the optimizer is very wrong. Try an `analyze table A;`. Try producing a SQL-Fiddle? Sounds really interesting, but I'll be off for today

Comment: I edited your answer with the EXPLAIN. I'll try all your suggestions tomorrow and update. Thanks a bunch for the suggestions given so far :)

Comment: Be careful with "ANALYZE TABLE", it is still MyISAM and there 500M take their time with blocking of the table. This Explain shows a catastrophe.

Comment: About the big blocks - it's by design of the underlying system not possible that a specific id_b entitiy is connected to more than 12 id_c entities.

Comment: I did mean big blocks with the same id_b, since they are scanned (after the few rows with your given id_c are found, you have only id_b as a criteria).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, too :)